# How to use ember-cli-mirage in an addon project

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli-mirage

I can't seem to get ember-cli-mirage to intercept ember-data requests when running `ember test --server` in an ember-cli-addon project.

/tests/dummy/app/adapters/application.js

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'rest'
});
```

/tests/dummy/mirage/config.js

```
export default function() {

  this.namespace = '/rest';

  this.get('/subManagers', 'sub-manager');
  this.get('/subManagers/:id', 'sub-manager');
  this.post('/subManagers', 'sub-manager');
  this.put('/subManagers/:id', 'sub-manager');
  this.del('/subManagers/:id', 'sub-manager');
}
```

However, when runnning `ember test --server`, the following request is getting a 404 `http://localhost:7357/rest/subManagers` when my test is requesting all subManagers and I am getting a test error `Error: Adapter operation failed`.

The tests are running on `http://localhost:7357/6263/tests/index.html?hidepassed`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe this was [recently fixed](https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage/pull/543), you may want to try master.

Comment: I found that too.  I updated package.json to `"ember-cli-mirage": "https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage.git"` but it still didn't work.    What is the correct way to point to master?

Comment: Did you run `npm update ember-cli-mirage` after changing package.json?

Comment: Yes, I even deleted the ember-cli-mirage folder.  And I had to move `tests/dummy/app/mirage` to `tests/dummy/mirage` to conform with the new structure.